# Как сгенерировать Exception с собственным описанием при использовании лямда синтаксиса?

Tags: java, исключения, потоки-данных, lambda

Использую лямбда синтаксис, последний оператор стрима

```
.orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
```

Как при таком синтаксисе создать исключение со своим описанием? Аналогично такому коду

```
new NotFoundException("My message");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("my message"))